# Monaco Editor Custom Defined Language Intellisense

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I am new to Monaco editor. I am trying to include Monaco editor in my web application. I want to know how can I add a custom language defined by me into Monaco editor with rich IntelliSense and validation. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by defining your own custom [`CompletionItemProvider`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitemprovider.html).

I suggest you take a look at the [Completion provider example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example) to get yourself started.

Comment: CompletionItemProviders triggerCharacters will be used to automatically open suggestions but only if autoSuggest is set in options.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an CompletionItemProvider with keywords that were dynamically added.

```
 monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('CustomExpressionLanguage', {
                provideCompletionItems: () => {
                    if (!items || items.length <= 0)
                        return { suggestions: [] };

                    window.varSuggestions = items.map(function (x) {
                        const one = {
                            label: x.Value,
                            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
                            insertText: `Col("${x.Key}")`,
                            insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet
                        };
                        return one;
                    });

                    window.pythonSuggestions = window.pythonMathMethods.map((x) => {
                        var item = {
                            label: x.label,
                            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Funcion,
                            insertText: `${x.label}${x.arguments}`,
                            documentation: x.documentation,
                            insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet
                        };
                        return item;
                    });

                    window.suggestions = window.varSuggestions.concat(window.pythonSuggestions);
                    return { suggestions: window.suggestions };
                }
            });
```